# How to get only required data from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one array called `attrs` with multiple objects.

when I print `console.log(attrs)` I will get this

```
id:"123432"
class:"delivery"
selectParams:"{address:currentDelivery.customerDetails.dropID, type:'doorDelivery'}"
```

With in that I have one object  called `selectParams` like this,

```
selectParams:"{address:currentDelivery.customerDetails.dropID, type:'doorDelivery'}"
console.log(attrs.selectParams)
```

I have printed that object and I got solution like this,

```
{address:currentDelivery.customerDetails.dropID, type:'doorDelivery'}
```

Now I need only `type` from this object and I tried to print like this,

```
console.log(attrs.selectParams.type)

console.log(attrs.selectParams[0].type)
```

But am getting undefined for both consoles.How to get only type?

Comment: `var a=attrs.selectParams;
var b=JSON.parse(a);
console.log(b)` this is what I have tried, am getting error `Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like from your first line of code that the object has been stringified. Try

```
JSON.parse(selectParams).type
```

Comment: This is not JSON. Well at least it is not valid to use `JSON.parse` on it.

Comment: Yes thats true Yury, I was just hoping that it was actually valid JSON and was just copied over incorrectly, since its pretty strange to have an object as a string and have it not be actual stringified JSON. 

Comment: when I try to like this ,am getting error `Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your object is actually a `string` because it's values is in the `""`. If you can populate your property according to `JSON` you can easily get it via

```js
const selectParams = '{"address":"currentDelivery.customerDetails.dropID", "type":"doorDelivery"}';

console.log(JSON.parse(selectParams).type)
```

If you can't do that and also can't create an object not string, you need to split your string into parts and get that one.

But I think you can make it an `object` or `JSON` format.

Comment: when I try to like this ,am getting error `Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Because you are trying to parse a JSON. Don't parse it if it's already a JSON

Comment: @krish do you have proper `JSON` format?. Can you show it?

Comment: @krish show the full attrs array...so that u will get solution fast

Answer (score 1):

How about using REGEX?

```js
var text9393 = "{address:currentDelivery.customerDetails.dropID,type:'doorDelivery'}"

var test = /type:'(.*?)'/.exec(text9393);

console.log(test[1]);
```

If you have multiple of the same string you can use:

```
var test = /type:'(.*?)'/.exec(text9393)[0];
```

The 0 on the end will pick the first object that comes by with the conditions of the regex expression. Change it to 1 and it will pick the second.

If you want the expression to be more specific then you can edit this expression using [RegExr.com](http://regexr.com/)

This is what it selects now:

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Edited the snippet so the code only shows **doorDelivery** so it does not show an array but just the value inside type.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution:

```
var a=attrs.selectParams;
var b=a.split(':')[2].replace(/}|'/g,' ').trim()
```